# How to create a NOT LOGGED IN Customer from Magento frontend?

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, customer-group

I want to create a customer from frontend with customer group should be "NOT LOGGED IN". I checked that it and no answer available for this.

Please help me in sort out this.

Comment: have you checked my update answer?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to override Model function Or put it file to local folder:**

> app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Group/Collection.php

```
public function setRealGroupsFilter()
{
    return $this->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt' => 0));
}
```

**Replace To:**

```
public function setRealGroupsFilter()
{
    return $this->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gteq' => 0));
}
```

Select default group: `admin > configuration > Costomer configuration > Create new account option > Default Group` "NOT LOGGED IN"

**Enjoy :)**

Comment: I don't want to add any observer. I just want to create a customer from frontend whose customer group should be "NOT LOGGED IN". is it possble ?

Comment: Yes possible check my updated answer

Comment: There is no option to set default group as "NOT LOGGED IN" and i don't want to edit code. Just as a regular user, i want to create a customer on website

Comment: Not possible without edit code

Answer (score -1):

Change the group from here from admin area:-
System > configuration > Customer configuration > create new account option  > Default Group